# Create a column that is a conditional smoothed moving average of another column in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

**My Problem**

I am trying to create a column in python which is the conditional smoothed moving 14 day average of another column. The condition is that I only want to include positive values from another column in the rolling average.

I am currently using the following code which works exactly how I want it to, but it is really slow because of the loops. I want to try and re-do it without using loops. The dataset is simply the last closing price of a stock.

**Current Working Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv1 = pd.read_csv('stock_price.csv', delimiter = ',')
df = pd.DataFrame(csv1)

df['delta'] = df.PX_LAST.pct_change()

df.loc[df.index[0], 'avg_gain'] = 0

for x in range(1,len(df.index)):
    if df["delta"].iloc[x] > 0:
        df["avg_gain"].iloc[x] = ((df["avg_gain"].iloc[x - 1] * 13) + df["delta"].iloc[x]) / 14
    else:
        df["avg_gain"].iloc[x] = ((df["avg_gain"].iloc[x - 1] * 13) + 0) / 14

df
```

**Correct Output Example**

```
Dates PX_LAST delta avg_gain
03/09/2018 43.67800 NaN 0.000000 
04/09/2018 43.14825 -0.012129 0.000000 
05/09/2018 42.81725 -0.007671 0.000000 
06/09/2018 43.07725 0.006072 0.000434 
07/09/2018 43.37525 0.006918 0.000897 
10/09/2018 43.47925 0.002398 0.001004 
11/09/2018 43.59750 0.002720 0.001127 
12/09/2018 43.68725 0.002059 0.001193 
13/09/2018 44.08925 0.009202 0.001765 
14/09/2018 43.89075 -0.004502 0.001639 
17/09/2018 44.04200 0.003446 0.001768
```

**Attempted Solutions**

I tried to create a new column that only comprises of the positive values and then tried to create the smoothed moving average of that new column but it doesn't give me the right answer

```
df['new_col'] = df['delta'].apply(lambda x: x if x > 0 else 0)
df['avg_gain'] = df['new_col'].ewm(14,min_periods=1).mean()
```

The maths behind it as follows...

Avg_Gain = ((Avg_Gain(t-1) * 13) + (New_Col * 1)) / 14

where New_Col only equals the positive values of Delta

Does anyone know how I might be able to do it?

Cheers

Comment: Can you post some portion of dataframe representing the input & also expected output

Comment: No problem. I have now included it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This should speed up your code:

`df['avg_gain'] = df[df['delta'] > 0]['delta'].rolling(14).mean()`

Does your current code converge to zero? If you can provide the data, then it would be easier for the folk to do some analysis.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I tried this solution but it just gives me "NaN". I have edited the post to include the input data and expected output if that helps?

Comment: What your code does is it doesn't include the previous 14 elements but multiples 13 with the one previous element, is that what you want to do or do you want the mean of the past 14 days? Also, when you mean you are expecting it to converge, are you saying your average should be closer to zero as the values keep decreasing?

Comment: Sorry, yep that is correct. The average should go to zero if the values keep decreasing. I'm struggling to find some code that can do that

Comment: But from your sample data, it does not look like the values are steadily decreasing.

Comment: Agreed. The values increase and decrease throughout the series. I was just making the point that if the values did only decrease (i.e. the rolling mean doesn't take into account any positive increases) then I would expect the rolling mean to converge to 0

Comment: You average would not be a zero unless all the non-negative values used to calculate the average are zero. May be I am missing something that you want?

Comment: the average would only ever be zero if all delta values (change in PX_LAST) would be negative. Otherwise, the average would never be zero. Even if there was only one delta value which equals a positive value then the mean would slowly converge to zero over N values but it would never touch. It is essentially just a smoothed moving average

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add a column which is 0 if the value is < 0 and instead has the same value as the one you want to consider if it is >= 0. Then you take the running average of this new column.

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['delta'] if x['delta'] >= 0 else 0)
df['avg_gain'] = df['new_value'].rolling(14).mean()
```

This would take into account zeros instead of just discarding them.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I realized this cant work because it doesn't take into account the previous value in the column and will not converge to zero if there are no positive values

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean: `.rolling(14)` takes into account the neighbouring values (if before/after/around the current value is set via one of the parameters), then `mean()` takes the mean of these 14 values. `df['new_col']` is a copy of `df['delta']` in which negative values are replaced with zeros